# Working with .$on in angular js

Tags: angularjs

How to get the current value in my html page using $on ?
My code is :

```
$scope.$on('slideEnded', function() {
    var startClass, endClass, sPos,ePos;
    startClass = $scope.componentDetails.stepArray[$scope.componentDetails.value];
    endClass = $scope.componentDetails.stepArray[$scope.componentDetails.maxVal];


    // console.log(startClass + endClass)
    getBatchSliders(startClass, endClass)

 });


function getBatchSliders(startClass, endClass) {
    endClass=parseInt(endClass);
    var totalSlider;

    if (startClass !== 'LKG' || startClass !== 'UKG') {
        totalSlider = endClass;
        //console.log("LKG not found")
    }
    if (startClass === 'LKG') {
        totalSlider = endClass + 2
        //console.log("LKG found")
    }
    $scope.totalSliders=totalSlider;
    console.log($scope.totalSliders)
 }
```

Now I want to pass "totalSliders" value to my html page ?
When I used this {{totalSliders}} its not get the current value?

Comment: Does `console.log($scope.totalSliders)` display the value you expect it to? And can we see the HTML where `{{totalSliders}}` is users?

Comment: yes in console I,m getting the value.But In html it shows the previous value.

Comment: put this inside $scope.apply as : $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.totalSliders=totalSlider;
        });

Comment: @anupam Its works..
Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are assigning a value to `totalSliders`, the binding will be lost after the first time you set it.

Use a view model object to persist the state:

```
$scope.vm = {}; // <-------------- initialize the vm here

$scope.$on('slideEnded', function() {
    var startClass, endClass, sPos,ePos;
    startClass = $scope.componentDetails.stepArray[$scope.componentDetails.value];
    endClass = $scope.componentDetails.stepArray[$scope.componentDetails.maxVal];    


    // console.log(startClass + endClass)
    getBatchSliders(startClass, endClass)
 });


function getBatchSliders(startClass, endClass) {
    endClass=parseInt(endClass);
    var totalSlider;

    if (startClass !== 'LKG' || startClass !== 'UKG') {
        totalSlider = endClass;
        //console.log("LKG not found")
    }
    if (startClass === 'LKG') {
        totalSlider = endClass + 2
        //console.log("LKG found")
    }
    $scope.vm.totalSliders = totalSlider;  //  <--------------  use the vm here
    console.log($scope.vm.totalSliders)
 }
```

Then bind to `{{vm.totalSliders}}` instead of just `{{totalSliders}}`